# Popping/crackling sounds and audio stuttering after resuming from suspend

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio

I have a computer with Ubuntu 16.04 connected through HDMI to a TV. A couple of days ago it started to make popping/crackling noises at random intervals (average ~5s). While playing video (with vlc or any other video player), the popping stops, but the audio stutters at approximately the same intervals.

Some information that I've aquired:

- The problem does not arise if I start my computer from "off"-state. Only if I resume from suspend (but this is what I want to do most of the time, out of practical reasons).
- The popping only starts after I play a video. The problem persists even if I then close vlc, but doing `pulseaudio --kill` in a terminal stops the popping until I put on a new video.
- It seems that the popping does not start by playing a youtube-video. But the audio does stutter.
- Having PulseAudio Volume Control open actually supresses the pops, but the audio still stutters when I play a video.

Possible solutions I have looked at:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230750: adding `options snd-hda-intel vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Did not help.
- [Popping noise from laptop speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160882/popping-noise-from-laptop-speakers): Setting "INTEL_AUDIO_POWERSAVE" to "false" in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/intel-audio-powersave`. Did not help. Also tried the other suggested solutions in the same thread.
- [Slight sound "crackle/pop" in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457243/slight-sound-crackle-pop-in-14-04): Messing with the `default-sample-rate` in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. Did not help.

Does anyone know how to address this problem?