# Crakling sound with headphones

Tags: sound, headphones

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my new Asus BX425EA (in dual boot with Windows). So far, so good, everything seems to work fine. Except when I use my headphones, I have a crackling sound. Also, if the sound level is low, I got interruptions.

With the laptop internal speakers, no issue. Also, I tried with another headphones Bluetooth connected (not mine, I borrowed it), no issue. My headphones don't have Bluetooth, I can only connect it with the wire. But the thing is, the laptop does not have 3.5mm audio jack plug: there is a USB-C to jack adapter (furnished with the laptop, see images). So, I'm pretty sure the issue is with this adapter.

[image: adapter_photo1]

[image: adapter_photo2]

I've already tried a buch of things without sucess:

- [tsched=0](https://kodi.wiki/view/PulseAudio#Known_issues)
- [Change some coefficients in /dev/snd/hwC0D0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910221/cracking-and-popping-sound-from-left-side-of-headphone-on-front-left-right-sound?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Change the sampling rate in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457243/slight-sound-crackle-pop-in-14-04) and also [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Choppy/distorted_sound)
- [vid=8086 pid=8ca0 snoop=0 in /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Glitches.2C_skips_or_crackling)

Here is some information:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC294
Codec: Intel Tigerlake HDMI
```

And:

```
$ dmesg | grep usb
    [    0.607211] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
    [    0.607211] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
    [    0.607211] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
    [    0.943429] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.08
    [    0.943431] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.943432] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    0.943433] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
    [    0.943434] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
    [    0.944854] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.08
    [    0.944855] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.944856] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    0.944857] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
    [    0.944858] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0d.0
    [    0.948837] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.08
    [    0.948837] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.948838] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    0.948839] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
    [    0.948839] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [    0.952030] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.08
    [    0.952031] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
    [    0.952031] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
    [    0.952032] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-43-generic xhci-hcd
    [    0.952032] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
    [    1.284729] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
    [    1.435947] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=56eb, bcdDevice=19.64
    [    1.435950] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
    [    1.435952] usb 3-6: Product: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
    [    1.435953] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: Azurewave
    [    1.435955] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 0x0001
    [    1.564734] usb 3-10: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [    1.715307] usb 3-10: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0026, bcdDevice= 0.02
    [    1.715310] usb 3-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
    [    2.650382] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
    [    2.733484] input: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/input/input8
    [    2.929418] input: USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 IR as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.2/input/input10
    [    2.929464] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
    [    3.122411] audit: type=1400 audit(1613637244.868:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=731 comm="apparmor_parser"
    [19759.503530] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
    [19759.724656] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0495, idProduct=3042, bcdDevice= 0.01
    [19759.724660] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [19759.724662] usb 3-2: Product: Asus USB DAC
    [19759.724664] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ESS Technology
    [19759.747506] input: ESS Technology Asus USB DAC as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:0495:3042.0002/input/input22
    [19759.807963] hid-generic 0003:0495:3042.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [ESS Technology Asus USB DAC] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3
    [19759.808051] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
    [19759.808052] usbhid: USB HID core driver
    [19759.832482] usb 3-2: current rate 48000 is different from the runtime rate 96000
    [19759.834471] usb 3-2: current rate 48000 is different from the runtime rate 96000
    [19759.874472] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
    [20528.125077] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
    [20537.776284] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
    [20537.997288] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0495, idProduct=3042, bcdDevice= 0.01
    [20537.997292] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
    [20537.997294] usb 3-2: Product: Asus USB DAC
    [20537.997296] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: ESS Technology
    [20538.025352] usb 3-2: current rate 48000 is different from the runtime rate 96000
    [20538.026642] usb 3-2: current rate 48000 is different from the runtime rate 96000
    [20538.063476] input: ESS Technology Asus USB DAC as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.3/0003:0495:3042.0003/input/input23
    [20538.120713] hid-generic 0003:0495:3042.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [ESS Technology Asus USB DAC] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you are facing [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183). You can try [this workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1648183/comments/17). It works for me, though my headphones do have 3.5 mm audio jack.

Comment: I mean my laptop also has 3.5 mm audio jack plug.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. Actually I tried but after the execution, Terminal gives me:  

`nid = 0x20, verb = 0x500, param = 0x67  
value = 0x0  
nid = 0x20, verb = 0x400, param = 0x3000  
value = 0x0`  
So, I'm not sure the commands executed properly. And problem is still here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trials without success, I've taken the risk to buy the Apple USB-C to 3.5mm jack adapter (10€ on the French Apple Store). Based [on this post](https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux/issues/94), I had a little hope it would work. And I guess I'm lucky because the sound is crystal clear! Plug and play, nothing to configure.